# Adding/permitting "staff" to read/write in folder

Tags: files, permissions, terminal, macos

For some reason, there isn't "staff" user group on a folder that I just created.
How do I add/permit "staff" user group to a folder that I just created?

This [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248699/how-to-change-group-owner-on-a-large-directory-containing-locked-files), seems to suggest to type this in terminal:

```
sudo chgrp -R staff ./folderName
```

1. Can the command work if I don't use the "-R"? I don't really want it to apply to the subsequent folders underneath it.
2. Also, this  [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/unix/comments/qrnud/how_do_i_add_staff_as_a_group_to_a_folder_xposted/), suggest that I need to also try this before:

```
sudo chown <owner's username> ./folderName
```

I thought "chown" is [change owner](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm)? Which user do I need to change to? what should be <owner's username>?

Kindly please be patient and guide me. I'm very new to this unix command. I just want to make sure that I'm doing the right thing before I stuffed up.

Comment: 1 ; Yes 2 : Not needed if ./folderName already belongs to its legitimate user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the group of a single directory:

```
chgrp staff ./directoryName
```

Remember that all commands come with documentation, so `man chgrp` can help to confirm this.